# background-fu pluggin unable to run ./script/generate background

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, backgroundworker

I'm following this rdoc: http://rdoc.info/projects/ncr/background-fu

and can't run `./script/generate background` after installing background-fu as a Rails plugin: `./script/plugin install git://github.com/ncr/background-fu.git`

I'm getting following error:

```
Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- job (MissingSourceFile)
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

tree/master on github is no longer rails 2.x compatible (they are moving on to Rails 3).  Try downloading the 1-0-stable branch tarball, decompress, untar, and put it in vendor/plugin.